# Chocolatey Self-Sevice how it works?

Tags: windows-services, chocolatey

Can somebody explain me how does chocolatey self-service agent work? I ask it in the sense of its design. I know that the agent runs as a windows service under defined local admin account. I am interested how this installing software without non-admin work. You execute choco commands from cmd.exe and it sends information to the agent service, and then service executes these command on behalf of you? Does it use some IPC to communicate with agent service? Named pipes maybe? How is this secure, it resembles in some way on reverse shell design. could something like this be accomplish with PowerShell OneGet?

Comment: Your question trends a bit towards off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet for the information that is public is https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-agent-service. The security aspects of this are also covered on that page.